# How can I identify whether checkbox is checked or not in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a checkbox with ng-model assigned to it, and customized ng-true-value and ng-false-value. Is there ng-something to check that check box is checked? Also I tried using ng-checked but according to  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked ng-model and ng-checked should not be used together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just assign ng-model in simple input tag having type='checkbox' like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="your_property" ng-model="your_property" />
```

You will receive true and false in 'your_property'. No need of used ng-checked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ng-checked, **ng-model** is enough because it can give you **false** and **true** (if checked).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Checkbox</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
  <label>Checkbox demo:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master">
  </label>
  <br/> My value is: {{master}}
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/NaTBRCeq1BeqtinEbK2t?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are searching for ng-if ?!
Include something like this in the plunker referenced on the angular page:

```
<span ng-if="master">Hello, I am checked.!</span>
```

'master' is the variable that is bound to the check-box of the input-element.

Answer (score 0):

```
there is no need of ng-checked. ng-model will have the value to true or false. 
<div ng-app="">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/>
      {{checked}}
</div>
```

please check the example in http://jsfiddle.net/19v90cnv/

Comment: I suggest editing your answer to include the code itself and just linking to jsfiddle for demo/reference.

Comment: Also, going from a link-only answer to a code-only answer isn't that much better - I'd suggest making sure you explain whatever it is that your code is doing otherwise it's liable to be deleted.

Comment: I have added my explanation. Thanks for suggestion.